# Using & operator in if statements

Tags: arduino, bitwise-operators

```
#include <IRremote.h>

const int RECV_PIN = 7;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
irrecv.enableIRIn();
irrecv.blink13(true);
}

 void loop(){
if (irrecv.decode(&results)){
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    irrecv.resume();
}
}
```

What will if check here and please explain the working also.how if is working?.

Comment: What language is this? Please add a tag.

Comment: If this is C or C++, unary `&` is not a bitwise operator, it's address-of.  That may be a hint.  This isn't something that a person would write naturally, so it looks more like a brain teaser or homework problem.

Comment: This is arduino language which is based on c or c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the & operator is used for the address of that variable. Using it in if statement will always be true as the address will not be 0.

Therefore your Do_somthing() function will always be called.

**Edit:**

In the edited code & operator is used to pass the address of that variable in the function irrecv.decode().

```
irrecv.decode(&results)
```

The above function will return true if a code was received, or false if nothing received yet. When a code is received, information is stored into "results".

For more info: https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_IRremote.html

Comment: hi i have edited my code pls go through it too nd explain whats happening nd pls explain.

Comment: @Noobcoder I have explained it for new code.

Comment: Thank you very much one last thing more if I remove the & sign will it change the meaning of code too?

Comment: Yes, it will. First of all, it might not compile in the first place as irrecv.decode() is expecting address as input, not the variable itself. The reason for sending the address to that variable is to get the updated value of "results" and also get the status of whether the value is changed or not via return of the function call i.e true/false.

Comment: thank you very much for the clarifications.